# CXF Transform feature

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am new to CXF,I have a requirement to drop few tags from the input XML .so I am using CXF Transform feature ,which should drop the version tag from my input XML ,I am able change but not drop. Kindly let me know how can I achieve it

```
<bean id="transformFeature" class="org.`enter code here`apache`enter code here`.cxf.feature.StaxTransformFeature">
<property name="inTransformElem`enter code here`ents">
<map>
 <entry key="version" value=""/>
 </map>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace of the element.  For example, if the `version` element has a namespace of `http://www.example.org/test`, you would need to configure the [CXF transformation feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html) as follows:

```
        <bean id="transformFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.StaxTransformFeature">
            <property name="inTransformElements">
                <map> 
                    <entry key="{http://www.example.org/test}version value=""/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

You also need to add the feature to your jaxws:endpoint configuration, if you have not already done so.

```
<jaxws:endpoint ...>
    <jaxws:features>
       <ref bean="transformFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```